# Switch on a motor circuit board

Tags: switches, identification

Attached is a photo of a switch on a Genie garage opener motor circuit board. What is the switch for? Almost seems like an insulating tab is inserted between contacts that should be removed before first use.

[image: weird switch at bottom]

Comment: your guess is as good as anyone else's

Comment: My guess... It's a reset switch.  Or it's a power switch i.e.  there was indeed a small plastic tab there that the user would pull upon first opening the package and thus making a battery connection.  (i.e. so they didn't have to actually install a battery)   That'd be kinda stupid but who knows?  Does the switch switch power?  Or is it connected to something else?

Comment: Is there a battery on the PCB? Is there a hole in the housing that lines up with the hole in the switch?

Comment: It's suspiciously close to that connector. Does the overhang of the connector press onto it by any chance?

Comment: No battery on PCB. The white connector handles 110 volt power input and power to motor. The connector does not touch this switch. More photos: photos.app.goo.gl/uVh8Wzv9UtgUhj7C8 . Check  video. Plausibly, the power can be temporarily cut by poking a rod through the circuit board and disconnecting the switch. The only other way to cut power is to unplug the main plug at the electrical socket.